# Use one or two php scripts for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one script of php which should check if given user exists in Users table, and if not it creates it, if yes then it updates the existing user with new information.

Should I create all in one sql query to do the checks and insert/update or should I first use one php script to get row count and then use second script to insert/update new user?

I know SQL but only the basics, so it is not my strong side.

Also which solution is better towards client/server communication?

Comment: Does it matter? I don't know best practice here, but personally I would do it in PHP. This has the advantage that if you want to change your db(-handler), you can reuse the code and don't need the db to support something like `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Comment: Agreed, use two queries, one checks a condition, then the other performs an action. By coming back into PHP,  you can perform additional logic, logging, checking, etc down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like to use this function:

```
function exists($detail, $table, $column, $value) {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connect, "SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = '$value'");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($count >= 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So if the user exists it will return true else false. After this check I would run another function / query to update a user.

the above function could look like this:

```
//SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'
if(exists('username', 'users', 'username', $username)) {
   //run this code if true
} else {
   //run this code if false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I just found that MySQL supports REPLACE statement, so it is exactly the same as INSERT only you replace INSERT keyword with REPLACE. :)

Comment: @Vlad that might come in handy sometime. Altough I don't know how much you care about security but a little check if the user exists might not be so bad before using any query

Comment: Probably better to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... rather than REPLACE. REPLACE deletes the existing record and inserts a new one. This means if you have a record that refers to the unique id of the record that you replace, it will now refer to a non existent record.

Comment: Good note. REPLACE creates new row with updated data but with incremented id. If the row before REPLACE was 47, after REPLACE it will be 48. Thanks!